# how to use keyboard input in a method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to JAVA, and I am having trouble trying to implement this code. Can you help me out? Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Derivative {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
        System.out.println(degree());       
    }

    public int degree(){
        System.out.println("degree of function?");
        int n = keyboard.nextInt();
        return n;
    }

}
```

Comment: _I am having trouble_ is a bad description of a problem. Do you understand variable scope?

Comment: [Here are the Java tutorials.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)

Comment: You need to understand [variable scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm). You've declared `keyboard` within the scope of your `main()` method, so it's not visible in the scope of your `degree()` method. Not only that, but you can't call an instance method (degree is non-static) from a static method without having an instance of your class handy.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared your `Scanner` variable in the scope of your `main` method. The `degree` method has no knowledge of any variable named `keyboard` that exists. If you would like to read more on variable scoping (which I believe you should), you can check out the resource [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). It explains in more detail the situation you are facing.

**You can do 2 things**

1. The first being you can make the `Scanner` a class variable.
2. The second is to pass it into the function

**Class Variable:**

You can declare it above your main method, for the class variable strategy like:

`public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`

An example of the class method is:

```
public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(degree());

}

public static int degree() {
    System.out.println("degree of function?");
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    return n;
}
```

**Pass to function:**

Or, you can change your method `degree` to take the scanner, like:

`public static int degree(Scanner keyboard) {`

and call it like:

`degree(keyboard)`

And an example of passing it into the method is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(degree(keyboard));

}

public static int degree(Scanner keyboard) {
    System.out.println("degree of function?");
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    return n;
}
```

**Extra:**

It should also be noted, that since you are calling `degree` from a `static` method (`main`), you should make `degree` a static method. Do so by changing:

`public int degree() {`

to:

`public static int degree() {`

Comment: Actually there is no global variables in Java. In C++ yes, but not Java. It is a Class Variable.

Comment: @user3437460 You are correct, that was a misstep on my part. I have updated the wording of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways in which you can solve this issue:

- Either you define a static variable of Scanner and access it without changing your method degree (make it static as you are accessing it from static method i.e. main) like `public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`.
- Pass scanner as method argument like `degree(keyboard);` and accept it when defining the method like `public static int degree(Scanner keyboard) {`.

Answer (score 0):

The methods does not recognize `keyboard` (your scanner object) because it is not in the scope of your  `degree()` method.

How do we identify whether it is within the scope? Easy, just look at the curly braces `{` and `}`. Anything declared within the curly brackets can be seen by other within the same pair of brackets.

That being said, you can do this:

```
public int degree(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
    System.out.println("degree of function?");
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    return n;
}
```

Bring Scanner keyboard into your method can solve the problem. (Now they are within the same scope).

**Alternatively**, you may declare your `keyboard` as static.

```
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```